# Working out if an array of line segments intersect

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have been asked to store and draw an array of linesegments.
The program should print the message "No intersection" or "Found an intersection" (depending) before terminting if negative coordinates are entered or 2x MAXSEGMENTS segments have been entered.

```
int main(void) {
    lineSeg_t line, allsegments[MAXSEGMENTS];
    point_t a, b;
    int pointssofar=0, i, v, w, x, y; 
    OpenGraphics();

    while (pointssofar<=(2*MAXSEGMENTS)){
        a=GetPoint();
        x=XCoord(a);
        y=YCoord(a);
        if ((x<0)||(y<0))
            break;
        b=GetPoint();
        v=XCoord(b);
        w=YCoord(b);
        if ((v<0)||(w<0))
            break;
        line=LineSeg(a, b);
        DrawLineSeg(line);
        allsegments[((pointssofar+2)/2)]=line;

        for (i=0;i<(pointssofar/2);i++){
            if (intersect(line, allsegments[i])==TRUE){
                printf ("Found an intersection");
                pointssofar=2*MAXSEGMENTS;
            } else if (pointssofar==(2*MAXSEGMENTS)){
                printf("No intersection");
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<(pointssofar/2);i++){
        if (intersect(allsegments[pointssofar/2], allsegments[i])==FALSE){
            printf("No intersection");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble outputting the messages. Think I'm stuck in the while loop and I'm really not sure how to get out!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: so that if a negative co-ordinate is entered it exits the while loop. (break)

Comment: I have a descartes.h header file if that's what you mean?

Comment: It was written by my lecturer and I don't know how to access it unfortunately. I have used it in the past and it has worked though. They do return negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

your while loop will never terminate, because there is no line in it that will ever make it's condition not true.

```
while (pointssofar<=(2*MAXSEGMENTS)){
```

the only time you change any of those values is that you get is

```
pointssofar=2*MAXSEGMENTS;
```

which satisfy the while loop condition.

you also have 2 `break` statements, but those are entirely dependant on the `XCoord` and `YCoord` functions.  They might not ever actually be returning negative numbers.

Comment: where should i increment it? (and how)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to increment pointssofar unless you find an intersection.

Comment: does allsegments[((pointssofar+2)/2)]=line;
not increment it?

Comment: No.  It just indexes into the allsegments array.

Comment: so how/ where should i increment it?
id i do it at the beginning the code only accepts one line for some reason. Thanks

Comment: Here are some hints:
    1) If you wrote GetPoint, then have it return -1 for a bad point
    2) Then you can remove the x, y, v, w variables
    3) The allsegments variable should be indexed by pointssofar when assigning line to it.  You have one line per loop iteration.
    4) In the for loop, your upper bound should be pointssofar (since that is how many you have at that point)
    5) Change the while loop to a for loop.
    6) Why do you have the second for loop?